# folder structure in Visual C++ when there are many projects depending on each other

Tags: c++, visual-studio, include-path, directory-structure

say I have a sln which contains 10 projects(named proj1 to proj10), and proj1 is the default project which generate the EXE file.

My problem is: how to place the 'include' folder?
I mean if proj2 uses proj3(that is including its header file and linking its lib file), how to place the 'include' folder?

there are two approaches:

1. place all header files and lib files in a different root folder which is in the same level of the project
2. make every project self-close, and the other projects who want to use this project should take care of the include-path and link-path. Of cause we should give a rule to the layout of every project(e.x. every project MUST have a 'include' folder and 'lib' folder in the root folder)

any suggestion?
thanks

Answer (score 1):

When it comes to Visual Studio, I don't like either of the two approaches you suggested, although mine is most closely related to your Option #2.  The way I like to organise it is like this:

```
<SolutionRoot>
  <Project1>
     project1.vcxproj
     someheader.h
     somesource.cpp
  <Project2>
  <Project3>
  <Project4>
  <Project5>
  application.sln
```

In case that's not obvious, that's a quasi-directory listing showing some project folders and the base solution file.

All new projects are just added to the solution using Visual Studio's default settings.  Trying to go against this and making projects work like Linux projects (`lib`, `include`, `src` *etc*) just ends up causing you grief, so don't do it.

Now, I set my "additional includes" path on every project to `$(SolutionDir)`.  Then if I want to include something from Project1:

```
#include "Project1/someheader.h"
```

The advantage of this is you don't clutter up your 'additional includes', so it's easy to see at a glance what *external* includes a project has.

As for linking to lib files, why not take advantage of Visual Studio's project references feature.  Honestly, your life will be easier.  Simply hook it up so that Project2 references Project1, *etc*...  Then you don't have to worry about libraries and linker paths.  You only do that for toolkits that are outside your solution tree (*eg* distributions such as **libpng** or **openssl**).

Again, you free up that setting so it only shows linkages outside of the solution.  The other advantage is that your build order is implicitly defined if you use references.

Answer (score 0):

I would go with the 1st solution. it make the project settings simple. As the C++ projects we worked on, we always put the header files together.